# How to dynamically get the results from `SqlQuery<T>` using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-5

I get the name of the entity that I want to query at runtime so I use reflection to call `SqlQuery<T>`:

```
Assembly assm = typeof(DataAccessLayer.MyContext).Assembly;
Type myType = assm.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(type => type.Name.Equals("Clients"));

MethodInfo genericMethod = typeof(System.Data.Entity.Database).GetMethods()
.Where(method => method.Name == "SqlQuery" && method.IsGenericMethod == 
true).FirstOrDefault();

MethodInfo generic = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
```

so this work fine I set my params - `object[] args = { SomeQuery, new object[] { } };`
and then I Invoke it - `generic.Invoke(db.Database, args);`.

The problem is when I try to get the actual records. I try to assign the invocation to a variable like this :

```
 var records = generic.Invoke(db.Database, args);
```

but records is type of `object` and in fact the value of `records` is the sql query that I've passed in records the invokation. The Visual Studio is giving me option to load the results but it seems that it can be done only manually.

Then I tried with with using dynamic like :

```
 dynamic records = generic.Invoke(db.Database, args);
```

which produce the same result, first `records` holds the string representation of my sql query, when I load the result I get the records as dynamic proxies but that's all. It's a little bit better since I can use `foreach` on `records` when the type is dynamic but I can't get nothing from this dynamic proxy that I get from the `foreach`.

At last I tried this :

```
   Assembly assm = typeof(DataAccessLayer.BankAttachmentsEntities).Assembly;
   Type myType = assm.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(type => type.Name.Equals("Clients"));
   var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
   var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Hoping that this will give me an instantiated variable of type `List<Clients>` but it seems not to be the case. Still it's recognized as object and I can't use `ToList` or other method that will load the result automatically.

How can I get access to the records fetched like this?

Comment: Why don't you just use the non-generic `SqlQuery(Type, string, object[])`? That will return a `DbRawSqlQuery` that you can `foreach` over. What do you need to do with the results? You won't know the type until runtime so your `foreach` will have to be of type `object`.

Comment: @RobH I need to serilize it to Json and return the data to the front end. Using anonymous types is perfectly fine. Since I'm not very familiar with reflection the problem for me was to get the `Type` from a string. So once I got this I decided that it's better to use the generic method. Now I'm not sure. With `Enumerate.First` I'm able to get the first record but `Enumerate.All` doesn't work. I still wonder if there's a possibility to keep the code that I have till now and think something about how to retrieve the result.

Comment: What do you get from `var results = new List<object>(); foreach (var obj in db.Database.SqlQuery(myType, SomeQuery, new object [] {})) { results.Add(obj); }`. If you can use a third party serializer like JSON.Net it will be able to serialize it for you.

Comment: @RobH I made a quick search for the this non-generic overload. I don't see a big difference, since `myType` still have to be a type that I have to get from somewhere. What is my advantage using this overload? From the examples I saw I still have to use dynamic and still need some concrete type to map the results...

Comment: It saves you having to invoke the method via reflection :) When you have a `List<object>` you could just use Json.net `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results)` which should give you your json.

Comment: So you suggest in `SqlQuery(myType, SomeQuery, new object [] {}))` on the place of `myType` to put `object`?

Comment: No, you still have to pass your type object into the SQLQuery method but you won't need to do all the 
`MethodInfo genericMethod = typeof(System.Data.Entity.Database).GetMethods()
.Where(method => method.Name == "SqlQuery" && method.IsGenericMethod == 
true).FirstOrDefault();

MethodInfo generic = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
//generic.Invoke` stuff